# Upgrade Android on a really old tablet (SM-T210)

Tags: samsung, 4.4-kitkat, custom-roms

I've recently been given a free tablet, a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 7.0 (SM-T210) and I want to experiment with custom ROMs and related stuff on it.

Since there is no official support for it and it still runs Android 4.4 I decided to do a search on xda and found no non-4.4 ROMs for it. Therefore, and because I heard it is possible to compile Android specifically for my device, I reached out to you for some help...

What information I have available:

- [Custom Kernel](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/kernel-4-4-werewolf-kernel-v008-15-02-2015-sm-t210-r-and-t211.2820573/)
- I was able to flash TWRP 3.0.0.0 via Odin
- The 7 inch variant has a Marvell PXA988 SoC (I heard it's more difficult to develop for?)
- Stock ROMs readily available all around the web (multiple regions).

What knowledge I have:

- Experience with flashing Custom ROMs and Recoveries in multiple devices and brands though I have never built my own.
- Know my way around Linux and more specifically Ubuntu.

I really hope that somebody out there is able to help me and tell me if it is possible to create a custom ROM for it. Why noone has compiled a newer version of Android and all custom ROMs out there have 4.2/4.4 as a base?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: compiling is not the stumbling step here, one must modify the config and maybe source code - which you don't have because Marvell did not release. there is one [lollipop](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3193423) build you can try (probably a kitkat port). lineageos has some building [guide](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/lt02ltespr/build) in case you get the source code somewhere

Comment: Okay thank you soo much! Two questions: a) The lollipop build you sent me is what I've tried (using TWRP) and it results in something like error due to signal 4. I have already modified the updater-script to no avail. Do you know what could be wrong? Maybe is it incompatible? Is there anyway to "force flash" this file just to see if it works? b) And when you mean the source, do you mean the kernel source or is it just something else I'm not aware of?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Building ROMs & Kernels?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/165210/building-roms-kernels)

Comment: a) you can extract zip and flash (converted) partition images via adb push b) kernel source code + aosp source code + hardware specific proprietary blobs

Comment: i recommend to build existing tree for SM-T217 only for learning exercise, you will get a feeling for compiling stuff. we can't help with this (i never built custom rom) it is off-topic here, only question about flashing issue is on-topic. you will find many experts on xda or stackoverflow